# Add user properties to Laravel passport token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

Hi I am wanting to add some extra properties in the access token generated using Laravel passport. I am using Laravel 5.6

Example Decoded token:

```
aud:"1"
exp:1528505818
iat:1528498618
jti:"10c880c491ecb73e39a6b1d7614b4be4e13ef4adf71fbc6f858a69899461fecc001fdefb60a287c1"
nbf:1528498618
scopes:[]
sub:"1"
user: {
  name: "test"
  role: "admin
}
```

I have read other articles but they only attach the user object to the response rather than encoding it in the token.

Alternatively, how can I add the role to the scopes array?

Have tried the following with no luck: (500 error: Trying to get property of non-object)

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Response;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login() { 
        $content = [];
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('username'), 'password' => request('password')])){
            $user = Auth::user();
            $role = $user->roles()->first()->name;
            $content['access_token'] = $user->createToken('HiveMan App')->accessToken;
            $status = 200;
        }
        else{
            $content['error'] = "Unauthorised";
            $content['message'] = "Your email or password are incorrect";
            $status = 401;
        }
        return response()->json($content, $status); 
    }
}
```